# Azure Continuous Deployment with Visual Studio Online and node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2015

I was flamed for my last post being too vague, so I shall be as precise and accurate as I can today.

I am a .NET developer now learning node.js. I am trying to set up continuous deployment of my node.js project within Visual Studio to Azure from Visual Studio Online. I have downloaded and installed the node.js tools for Visual Studio 2015 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx). I have successfully checked in my code to Visual Studio Online using Git from within Visual Studio 2015.

I have read lots of web articles on the subject but in each I come across a seemingly insurmountable problem. For example, [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/) gets me quite close to a solution, but falls over trying to Visual Studio Online. It can't find the repository.

No matter, I move on. I have now managed to get my Visual Studio Online code associated with my web app through manage.windowsazure.com (rather than portal.azure.com, which I find very confusing. Why are there two? They seem to expose the same functionality).

Now I am getting a "Deployment Failed" message in Azure, and the log in VSO reveals "Exception Message: Deploying to Azure Cloud Service requires a Visual Studio Solution (.sln) that contains either a ccproj or a lsxproj. (type DeploymentException)".

What can I do about this? I have seen lots of articles that describe publishing node.js project types to Azure with no problem. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks, M

Comment: Please refer to this blog about how to deploy continuous integration node.js  project on Azure via this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/nodejs